# Wifi connection of a target device not connecting in linux through terminal?

Tags: wifi, embedded-linux

I am trying to up wifi on broadcom BCM4334 chip .

I tried to connect with an open wifi network with following steps

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid beast_test
udhcpc wlan0
```

After this I get following error

```
udhcpc: SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device
```

I also tried to assign static IP

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.2.125
```

Then when I ping my router

```
ping 192.168.2.1
```

There is no response from it and ping fails.

Can you suggest me what may be the cause and how can I further debug it  ?

Comment: Search the system log for salient messages (e.g. `dmesg | grep brcm`).  Also check if firmware was requested and properly loaded (e.g. `dmesg | grep -i firmware`).

Comment: Here is the output I got 
root@ppbeacon-78:4B:87:5A:57:90:~# dmesg | grep -i firmware
[   22.642447] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Jun 26 2012 11:32:33 version 6.10 (TOB) (r335311)

Comment: dmesg | grep brcm
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyAM0,115200 root=ubi0:rootfs ubi.mtd=3 rootfstype=ubifs 3 gpmi brcmfmac.macaddr=
[   18.137802] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x16034334
[   18.177436] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_chip_drivestrengthinit: No SDIO Drive strength init done for chip 4334 rev 3 pmurev 17
[   22.572932] brcmfmac: brcmf_bus_start: invalid mac addr 00:00:00:00:00:00, falling back to OTP
[   22.642447] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Jun 26 2012 11:32:33 version 6.10 (TOB) (r335311)

Comment: [   22.744931] brcmfmac: brcmf_fws_init: enabled bdcv2 tlv signaling [1]
[   30.788671] brcmfmac: brcmf_fil_cmd_data: Failed err=-23
[   30.859469] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
[   30.866283] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event

Comment: That's unreadable.  You need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31744540/edit) your original post and append this information.